# How do I clear a buffer completely with elisp?

Tags: buffers

If I want to delete everything in a buffer with elisp, how do I do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you tried `erase-buffer`?

```
erase-buffer is an interactive built-in function in `C source code'.

(erase-buffer)


Delete the entire contents of the current buffer.
Any narrowing restriction in effect (see `narrow-to-region') is removed,
so the buffer is truly empty after this.
```

How to find such a function? `M-x apropos buffer erase`

Comment: There are a few exceptions, e.g., overlay objects are not deleted, and there may be some other stuff I am not familiar with that continues to be present after `erase-buffer` is called.

Comment: Yes, the question is not very precise wrt "*everything*" and "*in*" the buffer.  If you want to get rid of everything associated with the buffer, then `kill-buffer` is your friend.

Answer (score 9):

You can use some `setf` magic.

`(setf (buffer-string) "")`

Answer (score -1):

There's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17966635/411282):

`C-x h + del` key clears the buffer

*Note:* This requires `transient-mark-mode` to be enabled (which it is by default).

Comment: But this is a key sequence, whereas the OP asked for an Elisp answer.

Comment: Oops, posted too quickly.